# Automated attendance system using rfid mc522 with sms notification

Tags: database, arduino, arduino-uno, rfid, time-and-attendance

can anybody guide me steps how to design an automated attendance system using rfid tags/cards and connecting it with a database with sms notification? i just need to know the steps. im using rfid mc522, arduino uno.

Comment: If my answer below has solved your issue or problem, then tick the answer to make it green.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to add the rfid card ids of the students in an array. The process of registering card ids can also be done with some code I am sure. Otherwise, if you have only the arduino, just add the ids manually into an array. Then compare the id with each entry in that array and do something with it. Otherwise, if you have a Raspberry Pi, you can use technologies like NodeJS or Python to read the ids and store them into a json. the process is pretty automatic. Then, compare the ids while in action and do something with it. Like I have done it with ruby [here](https://github.com/tworitdash/pirfidiot/).

With arduino only, just follow the steps [here](https://youtu.be/yUtFinIsPWw). Just keep that in mind that you will have to register some tags and will provide access to them. For arduino, the database can be an array.

For sms notification with an arduino, you have to use a GSM module. After an id match, use GSM library of arduino to send messages.